# Light absorption spectra

Tags: visible-light

When looking through a spectroscope at the sun you see the absorption spectra of the elements within the sun. Why do you not see the absorption spectra of all the elements within our atmosphere as well?

Answer (score 1):

It is in fact possible to see some atmospheric absorption lines, most particularly those due to water vapour, which appear towards the red end of the spectrum.  The phenomenon started to be investigated in the 1860s.  With the invention of the direct vision spectroscope, examination of spectra to gauge moisture content became (relatively) popular among meteorologists, amateur and professional, as an aid to predicting rainfall.  John Browning, a London scientific instrument maker, promoted his so called "rainband spectroscope" for this purpose.

I understand that absorption lines from other molecules are visible as well, but are less prominent than water vapour.

Here is a link to a more detailed description. http://home.europa.com/~telscope/rainband.txt